# Theorem with seemingly reduntant part

Tags: linear-algebra

I encountered the following theorem in a linear algebra book:

For any vectors $u, v$ in $R^n$ and any scalar $k$ in $R$: $u . u \geq 0$, and $u  . u = 0 \iff u = 0$

I found the theorem in almost the same form online as well. Isn't the "$u.u \geq 0$" part reduntant here. That is, wouldn't the theorem still be valid if I just write:

$u  . u = 0 \iff u = 0$

This seems quite simple but theorems are generally precise statements where each part has a purpose. So there must be something fundamental that I am missing here. Can someone suggest where I am wrong.

Comment: Oh, maybe I now see what you mean: Maybe You confuse $u{.}u\ge 0\quad \land \quad(u{.}u=0\Leftrightarrow u=0)$ with $(u{.}u\ge 0\land u{.}u=0)\iff u=0$.

Comment: ah, you are right. I just didn't read the theorem correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two parts to the result. Both are true of course, but they say different things, so you need to state both of them.

Answer (score 0):

No. You could define $f(u,v):=-u.v$. Then ew do have $f(u,u)=0\iff u=0$, but we don't have $f(u,u)\ge 0$ for all $u$.